# What is the difference between ref and out in runtime?

Tags: c#, parameters, implementations, runtime

C# provides the `ref` and the `out` keyword to make arguments to be passed by reference. The semantic of the two is very similar. The only difference is in the initialization of the flaged variable:

- `ref` requires the variable to be initialized before passing it to the function, `out` does not.
- `out` requires the variable to be initialized inside the function, `ref` does not.

The use cases of these two keywords are also almost the same, and their too frequent usage is I beleive considered a code smell (although there are valid use cases like the `TryParse` and `TryGetValue` patterns).

Because of this could someone explain, why there are two very similar tools in C# for so narrow use cases?

Also, on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx), it is stated that they have different run-time behavior:

> Although the ref and out keywords cause different run-time behavior, they are not considered part of the method signature at compile time.

How is their run-time behavior different?

**Conclusion**

Both answers looks correct, thank you both. I accepted [jmoreno](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/26494/jmoreno)'s because it is more explicit.

Comment: My guess is they both are implemented the same way as `ref` in C++; to pointers to the object pointer (or primitive) in question. i.e. `Int32.TryParse(myStr, out myInt)` (C#) is "executed" the same way as `int32_tryParse(myStr, &myInt)` (C) would; the only difference being some constraints enforced by the compiler to prevent bugs. (I'm not gonna post this as an answer because I may be wrong about how this works behind the scenes, but this is how I envision it works [because it makes sense])

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At the time this question was asked, the MSDN article was subtly incorrect (it has [since been corrected](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/pull/11530/commits/a2f2b8eba74cad6972140c52650b4f8902544ede#diff-1ac621bef430021fa44b6e1a8ede1b4b)).  Instead of "cause different behavior" it should be "requires different behavior".

In particular, the compiler enforces different requirements for the two keywords, even though the same mecanism (IL) is used to enable the behavior.

Comment: So my understanding is that the compiler checks for things like dereferencing an `out` parameter or not assigning a `ref` parameter, but the IL it emits is just a reference either way. Is that correct?

Comment: Btw, one might tell this from the fact that `out T` and `ref T` are rendered identically in other CLI languages such as VB.Net or C++/CLI.

Comment: @AndrewPiliser: correct.  Assuming that the code compiles either way (you don't try to dereference when you shouldn't), the IL would be identical.

Answer (score 4):

here's an interesting writeup on the topic that may answer your question:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/ref

point of interest:

**"The difference between ref and out is not in the Common Language Runtime, but is in the C# language itself."**

**update:**

the senior developer at my work just corroborated @jmoreno's answer, so make sure you read it!.

Comment: So if I understand correctly there is no difference on the IL level, which implies that they can't have different run time behavior. This would contradict with what MSDN says. Interestin article nevertheless!

Comment: @GáborAngyal you don't happen to have a link to the MSDN article by chance do you? It might be nice to have that here if opinions differ

Comment: Here you go: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx, but it was in my question all along :)

Comment: What does `string` have to do with all this?

Comment: It's just a paraphrase from the article. Updated to remove second line..

Answer (score 2):

*Runtime*? Absolutely none.  You can't overload a method with the same parameters differing only by ref or out keyword.

Try to compile this and you'll get a compile error "Method with same signature is already declared":

```
    private class MyClass
    {
        private void DoSomething(out int param)
        {
        }
        private void DoSomething(ref int param)
        {
        }
    }
```

To answer this question: 
 *"...why there are two very similar tools in C# for so narrow use cases?"*

From a code readability and API standpoint there is a huge difference.  As a consumer of the API I know that when "out" is used the API does not depend on the out parameter.  As the API developer I prefer the "out" and use "ref" only when absolutely (RARELY!) necessary.  See this reference for a great discussion:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516876/when-to-use-ref-vs-out

Supporting info:  I compiled the following method and disassembled it.  I used the ref and out keywords (out in this example), but the assembly code did not change except for an address reference as I would expect:

```
    private class MyClass
    {
        internal void DoSomething(out int param)
        {
            param = 0;
        }
    }
```

00000000  push        ebp
00000001  mov         ebp,esp
00000003  push        edi
00000004  push        esi
00000005  push        ebx
00000006  sub         esp,34h
00000009  xor         eax,eax
0000000b  mov         dword ptr [ebp-10h],eax
0000000e  mov         dword ptr [ebp-1Ch],eax
00000011  mov         dword ptr [ebp-3Ch],ecx
00000014  mov         dword ptr [ebp-40h],edx
00000017  cmp         dword ptr ds:[008B1710h],0
0000001e  je          00000025
00000020  call        6E6B601E
00000025  nop
                param = 0;
00000026  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-40h]
00000029  xor         edx,edx
0000002b  mov         dword ptr [eax],edx
            }
0000002d  nop
0000002e  lea         esp,[ebp-0Ch]
00000031  pop         ebx
00000032  pop         esi
00000033  pop         edi
00000034  pop         ebp
00000035  ret

Am I reading the assembly correctly?

Comment: What you write is correct, but please note that it is not an evident implication that there is no runtime difference because this overload is not allowed.

Comment: Ahh - good point! Can anyone disassemble the code above and prove me right or wrong?  I'm terrible at reading assembly, but curious to know.

Comment: Okay - I disassembled the code using "out" and "ref" and I can't see any difference for my DoSomething method: